# Is there a jQuery thumbnail viewer plugin with zoom functionality?

Tags: jquery

I am seeking a jQuery plugin for displaying thumbnails and when the user clicks on a thumbnail, the picture zooms in to a bigger size.

Obviously would like to zoom back out when the user has  finished viewing the photo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider thumbnail gallery plugins like

[Thickbox](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/#examples)

[jQuery lightbox plugin](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/)

Comment: zoomimage is a 404 and thickbox is no longer maintained.